# How to check what is causing the high CPU usage on EC2 instance

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We have EC2 instance of type m5.xlarge which is having 4 CPUs but the CPU usage is 100% on weekend when the DB connections are normal.
How to debug what is causing the high CPU usage. we checked the cron running on server as well but everything is normal. 
This also causes the increase in DB connections on RDS when the actual site users are less.
Please help finding the solution.

Comment: What tools and methods have you used so far to try solve your problem? Have you tried connecting via `ssh` and running `top`? More information on your server setup might also help make this question answerable.

Comment: I have checked Apache logs, top, htop, df -h, sysstat but nothing found which causing this issue.